# Modify a char* in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to modify a c string in C++.

```
void modify(char* s)
{
    s[0] = 'a';
}
```

If I do this, there will be some undefined behavior and can't run.

Let's assume s[0] is valid. I know char* s is immutable. Is there any possibility that I can modify the s[0] in place, which means, without creating a new string. Do the modification on the original string.

Comment: "I know `char* s` is immutable." - then why isn't it `const`?

Comment: You can if you define the original string as an array of char instead of a pointer to char: char s[] = "This is a string"; modify(s);` (using `modify` as defined above) has defined behavior.

Comment: If char*s points to an immutable string, you're gonna have a bad time when you assign to it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, that's basically an error in the language. Yes, you can compile `char s[] = "hi";` but (on most systems) it's undefined behaviour if you actually modify it.

Comment: "char* s is immutable" - may or may not be true. There are mutable and immutable areas of memory, and this pointer could be pointing to either. We don't know just from what you have posted.

Comment: To the question "can we modify an immutable string in-place" the answer is obviously "No"

Comment: @MattMcNabb, The OP seems to have merged together the concept "immutable string" and "C string" in his mind.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: Sorry, but you're just wrong. If you have `char *s=hi";`, then attempt to modify `s`, you get undefined behavior--but when you use `char s[] = "hi";`, then the result of modifying the content of `s` is completely defined. I suppose there could be some system/implementation that has bugs in this area, but 1) I don't know of such a thing, and 2) it clearly is a bug--the C and C++ standards clearly define the behavior for such code.

Comment: And anyway, the unsafe conversion from string literal to `char*` is not allowed for quite some time now.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid `char s[] = "hi";` is equivalent to `char s[3] = "hi";`- nothing undefined about modifying it.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid `char s[n]` or `char s[]` is a char array.  Of course you can modify elements `0` to `n-1`, where `n` is the number of elements -- no different than any other type of array.  The only thing special about `char s[]` is that you can initialize it with an alternate syntax (i.e., a quoted string).

Comment: Doh. Yes. I meant `char * s = "hi"; s[0]='a';`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid - I know, it happens to everybody at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be misunderstanding some other answers you have seen on the web. 
It is only undefined behavior to modify a string **constant**, not any `char*`.

As long as you `strdup` the constant string into a non-constant string, you can make whatever changes you want with it, because it is now in a mutable region of memory.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void modString(char* changeMe) {
    changeMe[0] = 'g';
}
int main(){
    char* foo = strdup("food");
    puts(foo);
    modString(foo);
    puts(foo);
    free(foo);
}
```

Comment: Will the strdup create some extra spaces in the memory?

Comment: @CaptainRib, Yes it is equivalent to a `malloc` followed by a `strcpy`.